# Recreating Specific Female Vocals

Tags: voice, production, effects, reverb, delay

This artist called jacaszek uses some specific delay, EQ, & reverb settings for his female melody lines.

At 1:24 the female voice comes in.

Can anyone help me understand how he reached that sound?

Answer (score 2):

You can recreate the vocal sound at 1:24 by taking the vocal and "drenching" it in reverb (preferably a plate reverb) and then adding a pitch shifting reverb (but take care to lower the mix of the pitch shifting reverb or else it will mess up the sound). The VSTs which will be the most appropriate for doing this are Valhalla Vintage Verb and Valhalla Shimmer. You can also use slight distortion and bit crush. And of course, it goes without saying, EQ the sound using a bell filter which enhances the mid range. You can also use VocalSynth by Izotope to get better vocal manipulation.

The vocal sound at 1:38 can be recreated by using a simple Vocaloid software. One good example is the Yamaha Vocaloid. Again, apply all the above effects but lower their mix down.